# Adview contents don't match topic of my app

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I am useing adview in my app which tests about certain health conditions, but the ads that are displayed have nothing to do with the condition or health matters at all. Since the pharmaceutical and health industry are advertising a lot, I'm sure there should be 'matching' ads - my app just doesn't seem to invoke them!

Is there a way to 'tell' adview which keywords to look for or to improve in-app analysis for adview so it can choose more adequate ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand Google sells ad space to the highest bidder primarily based on user data rather than app content, which is essentially not factored at all. Were you to change the app category in AdMob for example from "Tools" to "Entertainment", you may notice different ads are shown, but you will still not be able to force specific ads to show.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's completely up to Google to determine which ads should be displayed. The behavior you're experiencing is normal since in the `AdMob` settings you can set which thematic groups of ads you want to show but they are so few and broad and some of the categories might be processed the way you see.